# Is Opting out of Google Play App Signing permanent?

Tags: android, keystore, android-app-signing, app-signing

I've only seen guidelines and articles about how the Google App signing works, how it benefits you and that it is **permanent** once you've opt in. But I can't find any proof that if you opt out once, will you be able to use it in the future?

Example: I'm trying to release an app, but I don't want to opt-in right now. In the future, I might. If I do change my mind, will I be able to opt-in again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Comment: I disagree. I am a programmer who is new to mobile apps and there are a lot of new concepts to absorb and understand. Deploying my apps to the Google Play Store is an essential step, so this is definitely of use to me as a programmer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can opt-in later. And once you do opt-in, it's permanent. I finally just opted-out because I wasn't sure if I'm willing to commit to this new and permanent idea. So I got this pop-up message from Google Play store which answers my question. I hope this helps everyone out.

[image: I got this pop-up from Google Play Store]

Answer (score 1):

The thing about Google App Signing is that the keystore certificate are stored on google servers and you don't have access to them directly.

For example, every time you need to update an app on the play store the app must be signed with the same certificate, so if you opt-in you cannot opt-out since the certificate stays with google and there is no option to download it at this time

Comment: If I don't opt-in now, will I be able to opt-in later (maybe in days, months, a year or more)?

Comment: I guess that's a similar issue, you would need to upload your certificate to them when you do this, but is it currently supported? Interesting question and answer. +1 to both.

Comment: Yes you can upload existing keys to their service https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en